# Karma + Jasmine serializing entire gigantic object on expect(...).toBeFalsy() failure

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have this line in one of my specs, which is a failing test:

`expect(game.scope.rows[1][2].char).toBeFalsy();`

I thought Karma was hanging on that line, but it eventually dumped some output like this:

```
Expected Character({ game: Game({ game_id: 'test_game_unit', time... }) to be falsy.
```

Except this string was 16 million characters long.

As you can see I have a reference in my character object to my game object, which holds the entire application state.  So it seems all the state in my program was serialized and dumped to the console.  Having a 16 million character string in my unit test output is non-ideal.  Is there a way get Karma (or Jasmine -- I'm not sure which is responsible) to not serialize and output the entire object when the output would be this huge?

Comment: Jasmine is responsible for that. It accepts a set of options to modify the output: `jasmine.MAX_PRETTY_PRINT_DEPTH` and `jasmine.MAX_PRETTY_PRINT_ARRAY_LENGTH` ([reference](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.3.4/src/core/base.js#L6)). Try to modify them before your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by dropping Karma and using Jasmine standalone.  Many things seem to be working better now.